# Reload page without the message box showing

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

Does anyont know how to reload an aspx page through javascript without the message box popping up asking if you want to refresh the page?

Answer (score 1):

Three different ways:

```
window.location.reload()

history.go(0)

window.location.href=window.location.href
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just been using (javascript) window.location.reload(), but given your tags (asp.net and c#2.0), I get the feeling that's not the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer I was looking for, document.forms[0].submit();

Comment: You are submitting the form on the page. That won't always refresh the page. If you're checking for (!IsPostback) in your codebehind like most ASP.NET pages do, the code for that condition won't get fired.